# How can I configue Gerrit to read iOS .strings files

Tags: ios, gerrit

I would like to examine differences in the iOS .strings files using Gerrit, but it doesn't seem to be able to handle their UTF-16 format.  Does anyone have a solution for this?  Or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't needed to configure .strings files before, I think the solution is to set the mime-type to safe.  See http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_mimetype_a_section_mimetype.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you run the .strings files through a mime type checker it just resolves as an application/octet-stream.

Comment: Well shoot.  I'd suggest posting on the Gerrit Google Groups page, it is a bit more active than stackoverflow.  You could also try irc - #gerrit on freenode.  Good luck!